# Why is this GE rated for 6 V, 200 mA, and 5 W?

Tags: power-supply

I have a genuine GE 5-1075A AC/DC power brick that says that it can provide 200 mA at 6 V (1.2 W).

My use case is that I want to power some old cassette players which I believe these are compatible with. The cassette players only list "6 V" and no current rating.

Why is this power brick listed as 5 W if it also states voltage and current nowhere near that value?

[image]

Comment: 6 volts and 200 mA is 1.2 watts. The 5 watt figure is power required from the AC to do what it does.

Comment: Input is rated 5W max. Power loss from input to output is called efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

[image]

In other words it's only about 20% power efficient.

Comment: It could use less than 5 watts.

Comment: And it could supply less than 1.2 watts.

Answer (score 0):

Because it consumes a maximum of 5 W on the 120 VAC side to give you 1.2 W @ 6 V on its output. Not very efficient, but there you have it.

Comment: More likely that the input is actually 5 VA, due to high inductance and poor coupling. This is done to reduce cost but also provides a measure of safety if output is overloaded or shorted. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393802/can-a-short-circuit-in-the-output-of-a-transformer-be-dangerous